# Show next record in recycler view in detail activity

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an activity which I call the DetailMantraActivity. The activity displays data from the recycler view. I want to add next and prev button. How is the code to add the next and prev buttons? This is my code

This is my Search Activity

```
package com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_search.*

class Search : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val MantraQUERY = "query"
    }

    private var query: String? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)

        btn_search2.setOnClickListener {
            query = input_nama.text.toString()
            val intent = Intent(this@Search, Result::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(MantraQUERY, query)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Result Activity

```
package com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu.adapter.ResultAdapter
import com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu.interrfaces.ResultOnClickListener
import com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu.sqllite.Mantra
import com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu.sqllite.MyDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_result.*

class Result : AppCompatActivity(), ResultOnClickListener {

    companion object {
        const val RESULT = "itemData"
    }

    var searchText: String? = null
    var id: Int? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)
        id = intent.getIntExtra(Kramaning.ID_MANTRA, 0)
        searchText = intent.getStringExtra(Search.MantraQUERY)

        if (id != 0) {
            showData(id!!)
        } else {
            if (searchText !=null ) {
                showSearchData("%$searchText%")
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pencarian $searchText", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun showSearchData(searchText: String) {
        val data = MyDatabase.getInstance().mantraDao().getNameMantra(searchText)
        val adapter = ResultAdapter(data, this)
        rv_result.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rv_result.adapter = adapter
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "DefaultLocale")
    private fun showData(id: Int) {

        val data = MyDatabase.getInstance().mantraDao().getAllMantra(id)
        val adapter = ResultAdapter(data, this)
        rv_result.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rv_result.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onClick(position: Int, data: List<Mantra>) {
        val mantra = data[position]
        val intent = Intent(this, DetailMantraActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(RESULT, mantra)
        startActivity(intent)

    }
}
```

and this is DetailMantraActivity

```
package com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu

import android.content.Intent
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import com.pustakahindu.mantrahindu.sqllite.Mantra
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail_mantra.*


class DetailMantraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_mantra)
        val data = intent.getParcelableExtra<Mantra>(Result.RESULT)
        tv_mantra_name.text = data.name
        tv_arti.text = data.indonesia
        tv_diacritic.text = data.diacritic

          
             btn_share.setOnClickListener {

            val message: String = "${tv_mantra_name.text}\n\n${tv_diacritic.text}\nArtinya:\n\n${tv_arti.text}".toString()

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)

            intent.type = "text/plain"

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Silakan pilih aplikasi berikut: "))
        }



    }


}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Pass the position and list on detail activity. On next button position++ and on previous button position-- ,   get object from list by list[position] and display on buttons click.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm new to android studio. can you explain in more detail with the coding?
Is position++ put in ResultActivity and in DetailActivity data for next and previous record is retrieved?
Thank you